# How to change the levels of tab_spanner using gt R package

Tags: r, gt

The resulting table of this code gives the `item no.` for the variable `statistic` and `p.value`, but I want the inverse. I want `statistic` and `p.value` for each `item no.`. How can it be done?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(gt)

# shapiro-wilk test results
sw <- tibble(
  session = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
  item = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
  statistic = runif(8),
  p.value = runif(8)
)


sw_w <- sw %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = item, values_from = c(statistic, p.value))

gt_tbl1 <- gt(sw_w, rowname_col = "session")

gt_tbl2 <- gt_tbl1 %>%
  # create column spanners as already indicated in the column names by "_"
  tab_spanner_delim(delim = "_") %>%
  # format percentage columns
  fmt_number(columns = 2:5, decimals = 3)

gt_tbl2 %>% tab_options(container.height = px(500))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is an easier approach but one option would be to reorder the columns of your data according to the item number such that columns for each item number are next to one another and using `split="first"` in `tab_spanner_delim`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(gt)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

set.seed(123)

# shapiro-wilk test results
sw <- tibble(
  session = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
  item = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
  statistic = runif(8),
  p.value = runif(8)
)


sw_w <- sw %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = item, values_from = c(statistic, p.value))

gt_tbl1 <- sw_w |>
  select(session, ends_with("1"), ends_with("2")) |>
  gt(rowname_col = "session")

gt_tbl2 <- gt_tbl1 %>%
  tab_spanner_delim(delim = "_", split = "first") %>%
  fmt_number(columns = 2:5, decimals = 3)

gt_tbl2 %>% tab_options(container.height = px(500))
```

[image]